# Is "have" or "has" more appropriate in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I think both of these may work, but my inclination is that "have" is more appropriate in the following sentence:

- About 1 in 3 American adults [has/have] prehypertension.

Answer (score 0):

https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/subject_verb_agreement.html

See #5.  Purdue would say "1 in 10 has..."

5. Do not be misled by a phrase that comes between the subject and the verb. The verb agrees with the subject, not with a noun or pronoun in the phrase.

One of the boxes is open

Comment: Strictly speaking it should be "one in ten have ..." since the head of the NP is not "one" but the plural "adults". "One" can't possibly be the head because it is head of the DP "one in three", which serves as determiner in the plural NP "one in three adult Americans". Singular override is found, indeed common, but syntactically, "American adults" (or just "adults") is the head, thus "have" is the syntactically correct verb. (Your example "One of the boxes is open" is not a proportional construction, so different considerations apply).

Comment: I never tell my students to look at Purdue's document. It is not trustworthy.

Comment: @BillJ could you clarify what you mean when you say “NP” and “DP” please? And consequently, what the “head” of these things means? I can’t really make sense of your comment as is.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is 'has' because you are referring to the 'one' who has hypertension, not the two others who have not. 'One (in 3) American adult has hypertension'.

Comment: 'adult' is in the plural in the original question

Comment: Sorry, I didn't faithfully reproduce the example - my typing error, I should have written 'One in three American adults has hypertension' - however it should still be singular, as the hypertension relates to the one who has it, not to the other two American adults who do not have hypertension.

Comment: Well, we know why you say it is should be "has", but you have given no support for this. Not everyone agrees with you. See the comments by BillJ. And note that BillJ did not write an answer because his comments were not suitable as an answer on this site, and frankly neither is your answer. See '[How to write a good answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)'. Also note that this is not the greatest question because it shows ZERO research.